# Simplify for loop

Tags: r

I have two arrays `out` and `res` and `c` a number. I have this code :

```
for(i in 1:N) {
    out[i] <- c - sum(res[1:i]) / i 
}
```

Is is possible to simplify this code in a single line, something like this :

```
out = c - sum(res[1: ???] / i
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like `c-cumsum(res)/1:length(res)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorise this with `sapply()`.

```
out <- sapply(1:length(res), function(x) c - mean(res[1:x]))
```